# How to get top 100 files inside a bucket

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I have a bucket on aws and I wanna download top 100 of files inside the specified bucket. I can get one specific file using `s3cmd` likes the following:

```
s3cmd get s3://bucket_name/file_name.m4a
```

How to get  100 of them using a command? Is there any option for the get?

Comment: Which 100 are you looking for? 100 last modified? 100 by alphabetical order?

Comment: Why do you want to download the "top" 100 files? What are you doing with them? We might be able to offer a better solution if you provide more information.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I just want 100 of them! not in uniform random, but 100 of them as a sample.

Comment: @tkwargs I just want 100 of them! not in uniform random, but 100 of them as a sample.

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Indeed, it's a customized s3 over a personal server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any solution for `get` option (it might exist). A solution which I found is:

```
s3cmd ls -r s3://bucket_name | grep -o 's3:.*' | head -n 100 | while read file; do s3cmd get $file; done
```

Something like this for `rm` can be found [here](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd/issues/800).